# Why is the Xenial lxd image twice the size of Wily and its predecessors?

Tags: lxc, ubuntu-minimal, disk-image, lxd

```
$ lxc image list ubuntu:
+--------------------+--------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------+---------+----------+-------------------------------+
|       ALIAS        | FINGERPRINT  | PUBLIC |                   DESCRIPTION                   |  ARCH   |   SIZE   |          UPLOAD DATE          |
+--------------------+--------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------+---------+----------+-------------------------------+
| p (5 more)         | 6b6fa83dacb0 | yes    | ubuntu 12.04 LTS amd64 (release) (20160627)     | x86_64  | 155.43MB | Jun 27, 2016 at 12:00am (UTC) |
| t (9 more)         | 628c432840e1 | yes    | ubuntu 14.04 LTS amd64 (release) (20160714)     | x86_64  | 119.23MB | Jul 14, 2016 at 12:00am (UTC) |
| w (5 more)         | 9b9de680184b | yes    | ubuntu 15.10 amd64 (release) (20160715)         | x86_64  | 154.62MB | Jul 15, 2016 at 12:00am (UTC) |
| x (5 more)         | f452cda3bccb | yes    | ubuntu 16.04 LTS amd64 (release) (20160627)     | x86_64  | 310.30MB | Jun 27, 2016 at 12:00am (UTC) |
...
```

You can view it easier here if you have a wide window: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/20357656/

Why the nearly double image size?

Once I launch an image, the usage is much smaller in Xenial, 727MB v. 812MB in Wily, using du -sh /.

*Update:* Never mind the above question.

Once the image is downloaded from the image server, it shows as 138.23MB.

Why is the image server reporting a size of 310.30MB for Xenial release when it is actually ~138.23MB?

I did some digging and filed a bug: https://github.com/lxc/lxd/issues/2223

```
$ curl -s https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/streams/v1/index.json | jq -C  . | less
```

and walked to the only object with "datatype": "image-downloads". This is what lxd uses. I followed the path value at that object.

```
$ curl -s https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/streams/v1/com.ubuntu.cloud:released:download.json | jq -C  . | less
```

I looked for differences in the entries for xenial and other releases in that simplestream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the bug. https://github.com/lxc/lxd/issues/2223 Thanks for filling. ;)